# How to connect local admin panel with my Android application in my Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, database-connection

I have an android app but I'm having a problem connect with my local admin panel which connect with my MySQL database.

Now the admin panel already setup at the localhost/(...) and in the Android Studio

```
public interface Consts {
public static String JOB_PORTAL = "...";
public static String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/.../api";
public static String IS_REGISTER_SEEKER = "is_register_seeker";
public static String IS_REGISTER_RECRUITER = "is_register_recruiter";
```

.
   .
   .

but it still can't connecting to the admin panel what else do I missing out? or should I use a web hosting to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Since `localhost` means *this device*, I can assume that your admin panel server is on your server/computer - meaning that if you're specifying `localhost` in your app for admin panel server, you're actually specifying your **Android device**, not your computer.

If you're not running your admin panel in your Android device, you have to specify your server/computer's IP address. It'll be something like

```
public static String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.0:8080/.../api";
```

Read:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: If you're using an emulator, `localhost` for your emulator is *your emulator*, which is still not your server/computer.

Comment: oh I see, but after I changed it to my computer's IP address it still not working.

Comment: try `10.0.2.2`.